# Does a range based for loop over an array ODR-use the array?

Tags: c++, c++14, one-definition-rule

When a range based for loop is used to iterate over an array, without binding a reference to each element, does this constitute an ODR-use of the array?

Example:

```
struct foo {
    static constexpr int xs[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
};

int test(void) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int x : foo::xs) // x is not a reference!
        sum += x;
    return sum;
}

// Definition, if needed
///constexpr foo::xs;
```

Is the definition of `foo::xs` necessary?

While this code, and variations of it, appear to work fine, that doesn't mean the definition is never necessary.  Lack of a definition of an ODR-used variable rarely produces a diagnostic, since the variable could be defined in another translation unit.  A linker error is the usual result, but it's quite possible to not get the error if the compiler is able to optimize away every use, which is what happens to the above code.  The compiler effectively reduces `test()` to `return 6;`.

Binding a reference to an element would be an ODR-use, but that isn't done.

I was under impression that subscripting an array was not ODR-use in C++14 or later.  But the range based for is not exactly subscripting.

In C++17, I believe this example avoids the problem because constexpr class data members are implicitly inline.  And thus the declaration in the class also serves to define `xs` and an additional namespace scope definition isn't needed to satisfy ODR.

Some additional versions of the same question:

What if we use `std::array`?

```
constexpr std::array<int, 3> xs = { 1, 2, 3 };
```

What if we avoid the range based for?

```
for (int i = 0; i < foo::xs.size(); i++) sum += foo::xs[i];
```

Comment: In C++14 a range based for loop has `auto && __range = range-expression ;` in it, so I believe that makes it ODR used.

Comment: Wrapping the array in a struct is a red herring. The compiler must know the size of the array to be used in a range (or other structured binding) context. This does not necessarily match ODR-use, as you can declare the array as `extern`, supplying only its size but populating it in another TU. The `std::array` is a different case: it provides a `.size()` member.

Comment: I don't see anything in N4140 (the Standard draft just before official C++14) suggesting "subscripting an array is not ODR-use". The built-in `X[Y]` means `*(X+Y)` causing the array-to-pointer conversion, which is generally an ODR-use of an array variable.

Comment: @aschepler I'm referring to what was in [defect report 1926](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1926) and appears in §[basic.def.odr] as _"If E is a subscripting operation with an array operand, the set contains the potential results of that operand."_  In this case, _E_ might be `foo:xs[i]`, which is converted to an rvalue, and so isn't odr-used.

Comment: @Dúthomhas the problem can't exist without putting the constexpr variable in class scope, i.e. wrapped in a struct.  If it was in namespace scope, then it would be a definition.  In class scope, it's possible to declare and initialize a constexpr variable without defining it.  How can a constexpr variable be extern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the definition of `foo::xs` necessary?

Yes, because as NathanOliver points out in the comments, a reference is implicitly bound to `foo::xs` by the range-based for loop. When you bind a reference to an object, the object is odr-used. The same would occur if an `std::array` were used rather than a raw array.

> What if we avoid the range based for?

Well, if you use a raw array and get its size using a technique that doesn't require binding a reference to it, then you can avoid providing a definition:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(foo::xs)/sizeof(foo::xs[0]); i++) {
    sum += foo::xs[i];
}
```

In this case, the references inside `sizeof` are not odr-uses because they are unevaluated, and `foo::xs` is an element of the set of potential results of `foo::xs[i]`; this latter expression is of non-class type and immediately undergoes an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, so it does not odr-use `foo::xs`.